# How to set up telegram bot's name from an environment variable in node-red?

Tags: telegram-bot, node-red

Using node-red-contrib-telegrambot palette it is possible to set up bot's token from an env variable using the following syntax `{env.get("BOT_TOKEN")}`.

[image]

But is it possible to do the same for the bot's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate any fields of a node in the editor from environment variables you need to use the following syntax:

```
${BOT_TOKEN}
```

You can find the docs [here](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/environment-variables)

Comment: I know how it's done,but it seems not to work for bot's NAME.

Comment: It's a function of the core Node-RED editor, it should work everywhere (note the syntax you included in your question does not match the docs)